# React Native - Navigation error while import custom component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make custom component here (footer). Here's my code:

**Footer.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import {
        View,
        Text,
        Linking,
        StyleSheet,
        Image,
        TouchableOpacity
        Dimensions,
    } from 'react-native'

    class Footer extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
            title: ''
        })

        _pageAbout = () => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('About');
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <View>
                    <View style={{ margin: 15 }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                           onPress={()=>this._pageAbout()}>
                           <Text>About</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>

            );

        }
    }

    export default Footer
```

Then I import and call that component on Home.js screen.
**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Linking,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity
    Dimensions,
} from 'react-native'
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: ''
    })

    render() {
        return (
           <Footer />        
        );
    }
}

export default Home
```

But when I click "About" text, it returns

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   this.props.navigation.navigate) in react native

Please help. Thanks before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass navigation as a prop to the Footer

```
<Footer navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

As the Footer will be unaware of the navigation stack

Answer (score 1):

send Home props to footer as below

```
<Footer {...this.props} />
```